# Extracting intersection areas in R with threshold

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, r, intersection

I have two shapefiles. One contains distribution species maps(circle) and the other contains types of vegetation (A,B,C). I want to know what area of every vegetation contains which species. I tried the following:

```
vegetation_area <- readOGR(dsn = "Input/Shapes", layer = "vegetation_area")
species_area <- readOGR(dsn = "Input/Shapes", layer = "species_shape")
Results<-gIntersects(vegetation_area,species_area,byid=TRUE)
rownames(Results)<-species_area@data$binomial
colnames(Results)<-vegetation_area@data$BioGeoName
```

[image]

This is good in telling me which species occur in which vegetation but how can I adjust, to get True, for only shapes with more than 50% overlap, for example?

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses package `sf`, after building a example data set, the objects are intersected, which yields "clipped" polygons; afterwards, these are filtered to those comprising at least 50% of the species distribution.

```r
# build polygons for example
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
mat_A = matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0),ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)
mat_B = matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0) + 10 ,ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)
mat_C = matrix(c(0,0,10,0,10,10,0,10,0,0) + c(10, 0) ,ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE)
pl1 = st_polygon(list(mat_A))
pl2 = st_polygon(list(mat_B))
pl3 = st_polygon(list(mat_C))
sp_dist = st_point(c(8.5,5)) %>% st_buffer(3)

# make sf object and create a row number colum
pols = st_sfc(pl1, pl2, pl3) %>% st_as_sf() %>% mutate(p_num = 1:3)

# a plot for exploring data
plot(pols, col = "white")
plot(sp_dist, add = TRUE, border = "tomato")

# here we filter with 0.5 (or 50%) threshold
st_intersection(pols, sp_dist) %>% 
  filter(st_area(.) >= 0.5*st_area(sp_dist))
# Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 1 field
# Geometry type: POLYGON
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: 5.5 ymin: 2 xmax: 10 ymax: 8
# CRS:           NA
# p_num                              x
# 1     1 POLYGON ((10 7.598076, 10 2...
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but I'm getting the following error:

> st_intersection(ecor,species) %>%
+ filter(st_area(.) >= 0.5*st_area(species))
Error in UseMethod("st_intersection") :
   method not applicable for 'st_intersection' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector', 'SpatialPolygonsNULL')"

Comment: you must read your data with `read_sf("path/to_your.shp)`, instead of `readOGR`

Comment: yeah!! true! I will try this now, thank you very much!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!!! have a great end of the year and a happy new year!